# Routes are not working for Nginx server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I have created a project in Laravel 5.1` using XAMPP server in Windows 8 operating system.

Now I want to make this project live using Ubuntu 14 and Nginx server. I have performed all the configuration mentioned in below link.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Unfortunately  I am unable to run the project when I checked console I got "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated" issue. Use defaultPrevented instead."  Seems routing issue.  Below is my route.php code snippet:

```
<?php

/****************   Model binding into route **************************/

Route::model('user', 'App\User');
Route::pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
Route::pattern('slug', '[0-9a-z-_]+');

/***************    Site routes  **********************************/
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
//Route::get('/', function(){ return 'This is testing';});
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@contact');
//Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@getContactUsForm');

Route::controllers([
'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
 ]);
```

Below is my Nginx.conf file

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ;

root /var/www/carwalepro/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name localhost;

location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#

  location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

What configurations are required to run the laravel project on Nginx?

Comment: `Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.` has nothing to do with Laravel, PHP or nginx. When you say "checked console" I'm assuming here that is developers console in your browser, firefox specifically and that this is a jQuery error. Can you update your question with more relevant information? Error logs of httpd, laravel, etc, what you actually see, what exactly does not work?